# REST API Endpoint to generate SAS token for Edge Devices in Azure IoTHub

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-hub-device-management

What is REST API endpoint for the following command ?

```
az iot hub generate-sas-token -n myIoTHub -d myDevice --du 630720
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no REST API endpoint for that command. It's a computation that you can implement yourself, it's described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-dev-guide-sas?tabs=node#security-token-structure) and comes with sample code.

The command you referenced does it [this way](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-cli-extension/blob/dev/azext_iot/common/sas_token_auth.py)